# Is pg12 cache used with two SELECT on same table but different fields

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance, postgresql-performance

Figure a table with fields a, b and c

Figure two requests on this table :

```
SELECT a, b from table

SELECT b, c from table
```

Is postgres able to reuse cache for the second request?

Answer (score 4):

The cache stores *blocks* read from from disk. A single block contains one or more rows from a table.

As both queries read the same data, they request the same blocks. So yes, the second query will be reading the blocks from the cache.

Comment: Thank you, is there some documentation pointing this? I am confused with pages and blocks. Regards

Comment: @Slim: see here: http://www.interdb.jp/pg/pgsql08.html A block is stored on disk (and the smallest unit that can be retrieved), once it's read into memory it's usually referred to as a page

Answer (score 1):

you can take a look here https://severalnines.com/database-blog/overview-caching-postgresql as you can see, as long as the pages retrieved from the first SELECT have all the data in the shared_buffers cache it will use it.

Comment: Thank you, is there some documentation pointing this? I am confused with pages and blocks. Regards

Comment: the home page has a section for that https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/storage-page-layout.html but the link but into better words as the documentation can, but try your best